# Locating index of one list with respect to another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have lists `J1` and `J2`. I want to locate the index of elements of `J2` with respect to `J1`. For example, `J2[0]=2` and this occurs at `J1[1]`. Hence, the index should be 1. Similarly for other elements of `J2`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np
J1=[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
J2=[[2, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
Indices=[i for i in J2 and J1]
print(Indices)
```

The current output is

```
[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[1,3,4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index()` to find the position of an item in a list.

```py
import numpy as np
J1=[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
J2=[[2, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
Indices=[[J1[0].index(i) for i in J2[0]]]
print(Indices)
```

Output:

```py
[[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index() method to find the index in J1 for each element in J2.

Here's the correct code:

```py
import numpy as np

J1 = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
J2 = [2, 6, 7, 9, 10]

Indices = [J1.index(elem) for elem in J2]

print(Indices)
# output: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

`J1.index(elem)` returns the index of `elem` in J1, and then loop iterates over each element in J2.